# Yii2 defining environment of console application

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

How to define environment of console application in Yii2? In web application it's simple. You just have to add custom declaration into Apache vhost configuration and you are done. For example:

**Virtual host configuration:**

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production
```

**Yii2 entry script:**

```
$env = !empty( $_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV'] ) ? $_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV'] : 'dev';

defined( 'YII_DEBUG' ) or define( 'YII_DEBUG', true );
defined( 'YII_ENV' ) or define( 'YII_ENV', $env );
```

I have three environments: development, testing, production. So how should I set appropriate environment in console app? Because each environment has specific configuration, etc.

My application is based on basic app template.

Comment: You could simply modify console entry script : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-entry-scripts.html#console-applications

Comment: Yes, I know I can :) But still I need some kind of identifier that defines current environment. In web application I can set such identifier in virtual hosts configuration.

Comment: Well, this has nothing to do with yii2, there are plenty of ways to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the environment should always be the same for all console apps, it's a good idea to set it in `config/console.php`.  Just add something like

```
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'console');
```

When the environment should be different for different machines, `gethostname` and a `switch`-`case` would represent the cleanest way to set the environment.

```
switch (gethostname()) {
case "machine1": define('YII_ENV', "console-test"); break;
// more case statements
default: define('YII_ENV', "console");
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue a few days ago. The yii console app can not read environment variables from VirtualHost settings.

My workaround is to call `php_uname()` function to get the full operation system name that PHP is running on, and use that to differentiate my environment. If your three environment are running on three different (virtual) machines, you can try this way.

[php_uname doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can add lical file with environments, for example yii.env

```
<?php
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');
```

and in file yii add:

```
if (is_file('yii.env')){
    include 'yii.env';
}
```